# Stuttering bluetooth audio only with YouTube

Tags: audio, video, bluetooth, streaming, youtube

I own a pair of RP-HF-400B Panasonic bluetooth headphones. 
They work very well when paired with my Android phone.

When I use it with Windows10 I have stuttering audio when YouTube is playing (it starts without problems, then after some seconds the audio becomes stuttering). It is the same turning ad-blocker off.

But a relevant fact is that audio is perfect when streaming other services, like public TV web broadcast.

How is it possible. Is Youtube such a heavy load for the computer? And why it starts well and then becomes stuttering (sometimes it has some good time during the playback).

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit dated and you've probably already fixed it. Nevertheless what I found is when I disabled handsfree on my bt headphones the stutter seemed to go away.

Answer (score 0):

in 2021, I am still having this issue, mind you, its not an "unknown" device I am using either, V Moda, Bose and Jabra all the same issue. Plus, its ONLY with YouTube

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//superuser.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.